# Using Python for Cisco network admin

Tags: python, ip, cisco

I started learning Python and I am trying to find a usage in networking and writing scripts.

My question is more of a newbie in dev. I'm learning how to access SSH with Paramiko, then collect info from a device, manipulate data, and push some commands.

Is there any ideas or ways of what can be done and/or automated using Python?

Answer (score 0):

U can Log to the cisco router using paramiko and issue a show log in loop, if in show log command any BGP flap will occure then script will sent you a mail using win32com module or smtplib module. If any webbrowser application ( like trouble ticket system) is related to your daily job with a a cisco devices you can also use a selenium module to automatically manipulate a webrowser.

Comment: That good. I did few scripts out of Cisco devices which are giving me ideas where I can use them. I can see better what are the possibilities.